# Féminin des mots en -eur

Tags: grammaire, genre

Y a-t-il une règle pour déterminer le féminin des mots en *-eur* ?

On trouve par exemple:

- chanteur → chanteuse
- pécheur → pécheresse
- directeur → directrice
- professeur → professeure
- docteur → doctoresse

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le problème de ces mots est qu'ils désignent tous un métier.

Or les noms de métiers est une "pure propriété formelle"([1](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A9minisation_des_noms_de_m%C3%A9tiers_en_fran%C3%A7ais)). En général, le genre grammatical est totalement distinct du sexe :

> Une chenille mâle
>
> Un colibri femelle

*(Extrait de [1](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A9minisation_des_noms_de_m%C3%A9tiers_en_fran%C3%A7ais))*

Normalement on devrait dire :

> Une professeur
>
> Une docteur
>
> Une auteur

Cependant, à cause de la politique et de l'exacerbation des mouvement féministes, le masculin général des noms de métiers est perçu comme occultant le rôle des femmes. C'est un problème sociolinguistique.

Beaucoup de noms de métier, notamment ceux décrits comme subalternes, ont gardé leur forme féminine, alors que les métiers dit de prestige sont passé au masculin: genre réputé non marqué. Le féminin désignant alors, en général, l'épouse de l'homme occupant la fonction.

C'est en général l'État qui a choisi d'ajouter à toutes les fonctions des équivalents féminins. L'Académie française s'oppose à ce mouvement, considérant que cela aboutit à la création de barbarismes, ou encore d'une certaine ségrégation.

Un guide de féminisation des noms des métiers a été [publié](http://www.ladocumentationfrancaise.fr/var/storage/rapports-publics//994001174/0000.pdf)

Tout cela conduit à une certaine confusion dans le choix des féminisation, notamment en -eur. (qui est différent de -teur)

Comment: Très intéressant, merci. J'ai bien indiqué `pécheur` (avec un accent aigu) et non `pêcheur` qui, lui, donne effectivement `pêcheuse`

Comment: @M42 me culpa :P

Comment: En France effectivement féminiser professeur est considéré comme une faute, mais j'ai cru comprendre que c'est plus toléré au Québec.http://www.academie-francaise.fr/actualites/feminisation.asp

Comment: @M'vy Mea* culpa. :P

Comment: @Alenanno: Argh. C'est mon clavier qui a fourché :P

Comment: En quoi cela répond-il à la question ?! On dirait plus un *rant* sur le féminisme (oulala, les vilaines féministes qui veulent qu'on écrive les noms qui désignent des femmes au féminin !).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Si l'opinion de l'auteur de cette réponse peut être sans importance, connaître l'opinion de l'Académie Française sur le sujet reste un élément de réponse pertinent.

Comment: @mouviciel "Question : quelle est la règle pour former le féminin des mots en -eur ?" "Réponse : les féministes sont à nos portes, et je prétends que l'académie française s'oppose à la féminisation des noms de métier." C'est une réponse ça ? Je cite l'académie française : *L’Académie française ne s’oppose pas au principe de la féminisation en tant que tel*. http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#38_strong-em-fminisation-des-noms-de-mtier-de-titres-etc-em-strong

Comment: [suite] *en ce qui concerne les titres, les grades et les fonctions, au nom de la neutralité institutionnelle et juridique qui leur est attachée, l’Académie française recommande d’éviter, dans tous les cas **non consacrés par l’usage, les termes du genre dit « féminin »*** Tout ce à quoi ils s'opposent, c'est de n'importe comment des noms de fonctions, mais admettent que ça peut être consacré par l'usage. Maquiller ça en *C'est en général l'état qui a choisi d'ajouter à toutes les fonctions des équivalents féminins. L'académie Française s'oppose à ce mouvement* est tout simplement malhonnête.

Comment: Peut-être simplement qu’[*exacerbation*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/exacerbation) n’est pas un mot assez neutre, et que son remplacement *(par pressions, par exemple)* suffirait à rendre le tout moins controversé.

Answer (score -1):

In french language the word «doctoresse» is still in use by the doctoresses themselves.
The word «professoresse» is much less used (except in Québec or Belgium).
I personally prefer these words to the stupid words obtained by adding a final "e".
I never saw any satisfying feminin version for «auteur». But if one needs a neologic form, i would suggest «autrice», which would be the most regular version.

Comment: Lots of unchecked “truths” in this answer... I grew up in Quebec and had at least a hundred different teachers and a couple thousand classmates, yet I never heard *proferssoresse*, or maybe once as a joke. Also, claiming some choices are stupid is perhaps also not exactly the way to go on this site. -1.

Comment: @Feelew: [professoresse](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/professoresse) existe pourtant bel et bien.

Comment: J'affirme que ce mot [n'est pas utilisé au Québec](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3941). Il existe peut-être, mais n'est pas utilisé ici. Une autre vérité contestable? *Autrice* n'est pas un néologisme, mais une résurgence de la [langue ancienne](http://information.tv5monde.com/terriennes/auteure-ou-autrice-un-mot-qui-derange-23114), dont certaines personnes [font aujourd’hui la promotion active](https://litteratureportesouvertes.wordpress.com/2017/05/14/un-auteur-une-autrice/).

Comment: Of course, someone claimed the official Quebec way is stupid, but sadly enough, this won't make official their recommendation of a more satisfying term *(satisfying to whom anyway?)*, nor will it change anything to the fact this more satisfying term is utterly ignored in daily speech by the vast, vast majority of Quebecquers.

Comment: "Autrice" is perfectly satisfactory, and well known at least since the 1400s.