# Feminine variants ending in "-eur"

Tags: genre

I've just found out that *une professeur* ([link 1](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/professeur/64155), [link 2](https://dictionnaire.orthodidacte.com/article/orthographe-professeur-au-feminin)) is an acceptable usage. Are there any other femininized *-eur* words like this?

Comment: *Auteur* anime beaucoup les neurones des milieux littéraires.

Comment: Edited title to reflect the type of word sought (e.g. not "la peur")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Féminin des mots en -eur](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2005/f%c3%a9minin-des-mots-en-eur)

Comment: Slightly different than the original question about feminine variants of masculine titles, but don't forget there are also feminine adjectives that end in -eur such a la grandeur, la hauteur, la fureur, la profondeur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can find more information on the uses in French for this case in this link :
https://www.druide.com/fr/enquetes/feminin-des-noms-de-personnes-en-eur

Comment: Bonne adresse !

Comment: Hi Matthieu, welcome to FSE and thank you for this good link! In order to make your answer a bit more "independant", it would be nice if you could take some of the most relevant information from the link and put it directly here, so that if the link ever breaks, your answer does not. :)