# Traduction des mots liées 'abstracts'

Tags: traduction

J'ai besoin de la traduction de ces mots liées au PHD :

> abstract
> Review
> Reviewer

Je l'ai traduit

> abstract -> résumé
> Review -> Avis
> reviewer -> examinateur

Comment: I don't know what a "Review" of a PhD is in English, and I'm a native English speaking university professor. Maybe you could explain this term a little more. Who reviews your thesis, and what are the consequences of the review?

Comment: Un "reviewer" est plutôt un relecteur qu'un examinateur, non ? Et donc "review" serait alors une relecture.

Answer (score 1):

OK for the translation of Abstract.

On the other hand, a "Review" is much more than an "avis". With a review, the reviewer is providing a close examination of the content of the material presented in the article or the Ph.D.

I would translate "Review" as "Rapport détaillé" and "Reviewer" as "Rapporteur". For a Ph.D. thesis, the reviewers are not necessarily part of the jury, but the report(s) provided by the reviewer(s) is (are) in general playing an important rôle to help the jury to formulate an opinion on the work under examination.

Answer (score 1):

Le membre du jury d’une thèse qui relit le manuscrit avec attention dans le but de poser des questions précises pendant la soutenance se nomme *rapporteur* (jamais *relecteur*). Lorsque la personne concernée est de genre féminin, se référer à [cette autre réponse sur le site](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2007/32304). En cherchant des thèses récentes au hasard sur HAL, j’ai trouvé aussi bien « rapporteur » ([exemple](https://theses.hal.science/tel-02870550v1)) que « rapporteure » ([exemple](https://theses.hal.science/tel-03162831v1)) ; j’ai déjà vu « rapportrice » mais ce doit être plus rare.

Le texte produit par ces personnes préalablement à la soutenance de thèse est un *rapport* ([site de l’université Paris-Cité](https://u-paris.fr/doctorat/soutenir-sa-these/), [site de Sorbonne Université](https://www.sorbonne-universite.fr/le-doctorat/demarches-administratives/soutenance)). Je crois avoir déjà vu « rapport détaillé » comme dans la réponse de Bazin, mais je n’ai pas trouvé d’exemple.

Attention cependant au cas proche de la relecture/revue par les pairs d’un article scientifique. Dans ce contexte, la personne est le plus couramment désignée par l’anglicisme « reviewer » (prononcer « riviouveur »). En bon français, j’utiliserais plus volontiers « relecteur ». « Rapporteur » serait compréhensible mais à mon avis plus rare.

Cette personne rend à la fois un *avis* et un *rapport* : le premier désigne la recommandation de publier (ou non) l’article, et le second contient des critiques, commentaires et questions détaillées visant à améliorer l’article. On peut employer aussi bien *avis* ou *rapport* pour indiquer l’ensemble des deux parties.